# nao estou conseguindo roda a primeira animação do meu game

Tags: c#, unity3d

Boa tarde estou com dificuldade em entende oque seria esse erro ainda tenho so algunas dias no mundo da programação alguem pode me da uma ajuda

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    public float Velocidade;
    public Transform player;
    private Animator animator;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        animator = player.GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        Movimentar();
    }
    void Movimentar ()
    {
        animator.SetFloat ("Run", Mathf.Abs (Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal")));

    if (Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") > 0) {
            transform.Translate (Vector2.right * Velocidade * Time.deltaTime);
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2 (0,0);
        }

            if(Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal") < 0) {

            transform.Translate(Vector2.right * Velocidade * Time.deltaTime);
                transform.eulerAngles = new Vector2(0,180);
            }
        }
}
```

o erro a seguir ao tenta executa o projeto

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object Player.Movimentar () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:22)
>   Player.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:18)
>
> UnassignedReferenceException: The variable player of Player has not
>   been assigned. You probably need to assign the player variable of the
>   Player script in the inspector.
>   UnityEngine.Component.GetComponent[Animator] () (at
>   C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/common/runtime/UnityEngineComponent.gen.cs:45)
>   Player.Start () (at Assets/Scripts/Player.cs:13)

Answer (score 1):

O erro está no seu projeto e não no código.

Ele está reclamando que você não atribuiu nenhum valor a variável `player`. Dentro do seu projeto, arrasta o asset que você quer pegar a propriedade `animator`até a variável `player`.

Answer (score 0):

Você declarou a variável `Player`? Na primeira linha você poderia declarar como um `New Transform`.

No seu código está assim:

```
public Transform player;
```

Substitua por isso:

```
public Transform player = new Transform;
```

Espero que funcione... Abraços